# Confluent JDBC connector, where information is kept about last read ID and timestamp

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am running Confluent JDBC connector on my local machine and trying to figure out where it is storing the information about last read ID and timestamp.

As per https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/#starting-table-capture

It needs to be in `offset.storage.topic` but I tried to set the configuration but I didn't work.

My connector:

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "timestamp.column.name": "updated_at",
    "incrementing.column.name": "id",
    "connection.password": "test123",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "dp_status",
    "table.whitelist": "source_test",
    "mode": "timestamp+incrementing",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "topic.prefix": "test-postgresql-jdbc-source.",
    "connection.user": "test",
    "name": "postgresql-jdbc-source-gp",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/test_db",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
}
```

Comment: Are you running Kafka Connect in distributed mode or standalone?

Comment: It's standalone

Answer (score 0):

If you run Kafka Connect in standalone mode then information about offsets (so in the case of JDBC source the ID/timestamp) is stored in a local file defined by `offset.storage.file.filename` in the Kafka Connect worker properties.

Comment: I am using docker and I don't see any file at path mentioned under `offset.storage.file.filename`

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your full Docker run command / Docker Compose please.